# revealViewController() always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some troubles with `revealViewController` in Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.2.

My app starts with a view controller embedded in a navigation controller to perform a login.
After login, or if the login token is present, I jump to another view controller embedded in a navigation controller with the following code:

```
let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let homePageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homePage)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homePageNav
```

In this home view controller I would like to have a left navigation menu with `SWRealViewController`.

I had the `SWRealViewController` view linked with `sw_front` to my home navigation controller, and the following code:

```
if (self.revealViewController() != nil) {
    self.menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    self.menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

But `self.revealViewController()` always returns nil, so it does not work.

I think I lost the `revealViewController` somewhere (maybe when I jump from the first navigation controller to the second) but I do not know what to do.

Comment: How is `revealViewController` declared?

Comment: @Thomi Do you mean [SWRevealViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)?

Comment: I followed this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWDNScxZ0YU
I have a View Controller in my story board, with the Class SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient to be a reason for the `revealViewController` to be `nil`
is you didn't connect `segues` correctly in `stroyboard`.

See this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) it's quite easy to follow.

**Update**
If in your case you just need to open a login vc if the user is not logged in you may do like this:

**in AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   var rootVCStoryboardId = userIsLoggedin ? "SWRevealViewController" : "LoginViewController"
   self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboards.main, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(rootVCStoryboardId)
```

Where  `SWRevealViewController` is the stroyboard id for SWRevealViewController and  `LoginViewController` is the storyboard id for your login view controller(or its navigation controller if exists).

[image]

Comment: I think I am OK, my SWrevealViewController has 2 segues : the first is connected to the Navigation Controller (sw_front), the second to the Table View (sw_rear).

Comment: would you share with me your project( send it to me or via teamviewer) I might be able to fix it with you.

Comment: That will be impossible unfortunately. What information do you need to see my issue?

Comment: I was wondering... Maybe when the login is done, I should jump to the SWRevealViewController instead of my HomeViewController. And link the SWRevealViewController to the HomeViewController with sw_front.

Comment: What I want to know what do you have as an initail vc?

Comment: Is it only  a login ?

Comment: If so, I'm doing exactly the same in my project and it's working fine. let me know so I post some code sample for you

Comment: Ok I will try to be clear. My initial VC just contains a FBSDKLoginButton. If the user clicks this button or if the user already as the FB token I change my rootViewController to a HomeViewController (where I would like to have the left side menu).

Comment: Please see my updated answer, and let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: How and where do you define userIsLoggedin ?

Comment: let us chat through this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101581/ios-revealviewcontroller-always-returns-nil)

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is not 20 yet, so I cannot use the chat :(

Comment: I see. At least you could see what I wrote?

Comment: Yes I do see what you wrote :)

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is wondering how to do a manual segue, this is what worked for me at the end.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController

    self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

    let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! NameOfViewController

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)

    sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are skipping login scene based on the current user information, then make sure to instantiate the storyboard with `SWRevealViewController`.  See below code for reference:

```
if User.currentUser != nil {
        //There is a current user
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController")
        window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
    else{
        //No current user
    }
```