# SWRevealViewController - reveal it manually under @IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

This is my `StartViewController` with simple `@IBAction`:

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true) //error
    }
}
```

Along with the commented line there is an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong?

Of course `StartViewController` is presented from `SWRevealViewController` via `sw_front` segue.

For some reason `revealViewController()` returns nil here. Why?

This is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

Comment: I think you are just missing the SWRevealViewControllerDelegate in your class. Try the following

Answer (score 2):

When you implementing SWRevealViewController using storyboard, you should set *Storyboard Entry Point* to `SWRevealViewController` instance (Reveal View Controller on picture), not to front view controller (Start View Controller on picture).

Note that `revealViewController` method return optional pointer, and even when all is set properly it return `nil` until view is loaded, so you better use optional chaining:

```
revealViewController()?.revealToggleAnimated(true)
```

Comment: No, I call it when I tap the button. So it is far away after view did load.

Comment: Confirm please, that `revealViewController` method return `nil`: `if revealViewController() == nil {print("reveal init error")}`

Comment: exactly. When I type here `po revealViewController() == nil` it prints `true`.

Comment: Did you set "sw_rear" segue also? You sure that you did not forgot to set `Class` field to `SWRevealViewController` in main reveal controller in storyboard? You sure also, that you used custom "set" segues?

Comment: Yes, I did everything right. Can I share my project with you via github?

Comment: sure, I have time to check it

Comment: https://github.com/kunass2/SWRevealViewController. It is installed via cocoapods. It should be simple for you:) very thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114593/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-shadow-of).

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk just move your storyboard entry point (arrow) from Start Vew Controller to Reveal View Controller

Comment: You are amazing man:) How could I miss that?:) it works:) I really appreciate that.

Comment: Please update your answer, depending on my updated question. I will accept it.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk done. Also I still recommend you to use optional chaining, since you still can get nil from this method in some cases =)

Comment: I will do it like this:)

Answer (score 0):

I think your app might crash because you are missing a delegate.Try to add the following to your protocols:

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true) //error
    }
}
```

If it still crashes, try changing the     `revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)` with      `revealViewController().revealToggle(self)` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: It still crashes for both methods.

Comment: add this to the code  `revealViewController().delegate = self`

Comment: No, stll crashes. I dont think, that delegate matters here. For some reason `revealViewController()` returns nil, when it should not.

Comment: You did put the `revealViewController().delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad()`, right? Not in the button action.  It should matter, because if you don't do the delegate, sw_front isn't enabled when the menu is shown in the back.

Comment: Yes, I did it in viewDidLoad() but now crash appears in that method, because `revealViewController()` returns nil.

Comment: In that case, it isn't the code itself, but something might be wrong with the segues in your storyboard. Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987122/revealviewcontroller-always-returns-nil ?